# AngularJS: access isolated scope variable within the element tag

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Is this possible somehow?

```
app.directive('myDirective',function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      myName:'=myName'
    }
  }
}
```

. . .

```
<div my-directive my-name="name" ng-class="myName"></div>
```

or do i need to write my own directive?

Comment: you want to access the variable in ng-class?

Comment: It is possible but doesn't make sense to do it like this. You don't want directive to mess with things outside its sandbox (isolated scope).

Comment: @bitstrider, actually you can directly use `name` inside 'ng-class', because your controller variable `name` and directive's variable `myName` are same.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible somehow?

Yes, it is possible (using `$parent` reference to outer scope, for example) but it doesn't make sense to do it like this. You don't want directive to mess with things outside its sandbox (isolated scope). After all, this is the point of having isolated scope in the first place.

In your case, you just need to use `ngClass` with the original `name`, which is already available in the scope (outer):

```
<div my-directive my-name="name" ng-class="name"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <my-directive my-name="name" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
}

myApp.directive('myDirective',function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      myName:'=myName'
    },
    replace: false,
    template: 'Hello, {{myName}}!',
    controller: function(){}
  }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/20538/

Change the template with your HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate a class from your controller use:

HTML

```
<div ng-class="{{myName}}" >
```

JS

```
$scope.myName = 'value';
```